# datagridview background color obfuscated / dirty when selected rows

Tags: winforms, datagridview, colors, background

I've been looking for some hours but haven't found a solution about this issue.

I'm using the .NET 4 DataGridView in WinForms and it's presenting me some issues with selected rows background colors.

Rows become like dirty when selected, and any properties of the window change. For example: when another window moves over the grid, the hidden part of the field becomes unreadable.

I'm posting an image explaining this situation better than my poor English does.

[image]

As the figure shows, selected rows with lightblue forecolor became dirty when another windows passes over them. You will see that only selected ones become that way, as the other not selected green row wont happen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that there is a SelectedBackGround property that allows me to change the color of the selected rows, wich is not the same as the default backcolor.

That solved my problem.